# Laravel 8 Multi-authentication Using Guards Rest Password PROBLEM

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-8

## I am trying to make a Laravel App with multi-authentication using guards.

**Github:** [Repository](https://github.com/hilal-najem3/Laravel-8)

#### I created a Fresh Laravel 8 App and added admin guard and now I am able to login and logout in both admin and user modes.

**This Picture Shows the details of what I did you can skip and just read Admin reset password section below**
[image: Details Picture]

**config/auth.php:**

```
<?php

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Authentication Defaults
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This option controls the default authentication "guard" and password
    | reset options for your application. You may change these defaults
    | as required, but they're a perfect start for most applications.
    |
    */

    'defaults' => [
        'guard' => 'web',
        'passwords' => 'users',
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Authentication Guards
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Next, you may define every authentication guard for your application.
    | Of course, a great default configuration has been defined for you
    | here which uses session storage and the Eloquent user provider.
    |
    | All authentication drivers have a user provider. This defines how the
    | users are actually retrieved out of your database or other storage
    | mechanisms used by this application to persist your user's data.
    |
    | Supported: "session", "token"
    |
    */

    'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],

        'admin' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'admins',
        ],

        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'token',
            'provider' => 'users',
            'hash' => false,
        ],
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | User Providers
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | All authentication drivers have a user provider. This defines how the
    | users are actually retrieved out of your database or other storage
    | mechanisms used by this application to persist your user's data.
    |
    | If you have multiple user tables or models you may configure multiple
    | sources which represent each model / table. These sources may then
    | be assigned to any extra authentication guards you have defined.
    |
    | Supported: "database", "eloquent"
    |
    */

    'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Models\User::class,
        ],

        'admins' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Models\Admin::class,
        ],

        // 'users' => [
        //     'driver' => 'database',
        //     'table' => 'users',
        // ],
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Resetting Passwords
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | You may specify multiple password reset configurations if you have more
    | than one user table or model in the application and you want to have
    | separate password reset settings based on the specific user types.
    |
    | The expire time is the number of minutes that the reset token should be
    | considered valid. This security feature keeps tokens short-lived so
    | they have less time to be guessed. You may change this as needed.
    |
    */

    'passwords' => [
        'users' => [
            'provider' => 'users',
            'table' => 'password_resets',
            'expire' => 60,
            'throttle' => 60,
        ],

        'admins' => [
            'provider' => 'admins',
            'table' => 'password_resets',
            'expire' => 30,
            'throttle' => 30,
        ],
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Password Confirmation Timeout
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may define the amount of seconds before a password confirmation
    | times out and the user is prompted to re-enter their password via the
    | confirmation screen. By default, the timeout lasts for three hours.
    |
    */

    'password_timeout' => 10800,

];
```

### Admin Reset Password Section

I added the flowing functions to `PasswordResetLinkController and NewPasswordController for admin`:

```
/**
 * Get the guard to be used during authentication.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\StatefulGuard
 */
protected function guard()
{
    return Auth::guard('admin');
}

/**
 * Returns the password broker for admins
 * 
 * @return broker
 */
protected function broker()
{
    return Password::broker('admins');
}
```

**And then** I went to `/admin/forget-password` route and submitted the admin email but I got the following error: `We can't find a user with that email address.`

**After checking** I found that in the function `store` of the `PasswordResetLinkController` it is attempting to find an admin email in the `users table/model`. Here is function store:

```
/**
 * Handle an incoming password reset link request.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse
 *
 * @throws \Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException
 */
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $request->validate([
        'email' => 'required|email',
    ]);

    // We will send the password reset link to this user. Once we have attempted
    // to send the link, we will examine the response then see the message we
    // need to show to the user. Finally, we'll send out a proper response.
    $status = Password::sendResetLink(
        $request->only('email')
    );

    return $status == Password::RESET_LINK_SENT
                ? back()->with('status', __($status))
                : back()->withInput($request->only('email'))
                        ->withErrors(['email' => __($status)]);
}
```

## How can I force classes PasswordResetLinkController and NewPasswordController to use guard() and broker() functions I added to them?

**Sorry for the long explanation I tried to search for this question on multiple platforms they are only using the roles approach to do it, if I didn't explain thoroughly some might not understand what I am trying to do**

Comment: can you share the changes that you make in the config/auth.php?

Comment: Sure but you can get the full repository, I attached it in the question.

Comment: @Prospero file added

Comment: I do something related but using Fortify. In config/fortify.php I configure the password broker that Fortify is going to use and this are related with the multiples reset password configured in auth.php. In your files, where this is made?

Comment: I am guessing you are adding a package using composer that adds fortify. I don't know what that is rn though... Can you tell me its name so I can search it up

Comment: Also are you using guards in LARAVEL-8 ??? I can't see a proper documentation on that.. There are tons of the for Laravel 7 and below not for 8

Comment: Yeah, I'm using guards in L8. But I'm using Fortify for Authentication, is another package for that. This implements some classes and I can't relation it with your project, for example PasswordBrokerManager class and a fortify.php file in config

Comment: Ok I will search for the package and add it to the project after reverting the last commit/s .. And I will return to this question when I am done. Thank you @Prospero

Comment: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/laravel-8-multi-auth-with-two-diffirent-registration-form here is some related with breeze. Seem that you need to use middleware in route like this Route::group(['middleware'=>'auth:admin'], function(){
  // routes under the admin
});

Comment: @Prospero I tried Fortify it doesn't answer my question.. It only ads two-factor authentication. What I want is to send `Reset-Password-Link` to admins using email notification

Comment: Ok if you add Fortify (it's more than 2FA), you can see now PasswordBrokerManager class right? and config/fortify.php file right?

Comment: I can see `config/fortify.php` but not `PasswordBrokerManager`

Comment: The thing is I have a fresh Laravel App which I added the starter kit to it and then Foritfy. Is this wrong?? Should I remove the starter Kit? Do you have a list of steps that I should do starting from a fresh app that is `composer create-project laravel/laravel example-app`. @Prospero

Comment: No, I think. I begin a project with auth ui, later add Jetstream and now I'm deploying authentication with Fortify. The important things are you know what you need to deploy as project and know what packages can bring you for that requirements. I told you about Fortify for my experience doing something related with your post. Below I'm going to share you my solution of that, in my case I'm deploying a multi-tenant Saas app and have different users model, db, login and register views...etc. Hope this help you. In app/Actions/Fortify must be the PasswordBrokerManager

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you are using Laravel Breeze, replace this line of code in the `store()` method of the `PasswordResetLinkController.php` class.

```
$status = Password::sendResetLink($request->only('email'));
```

With the following line.

```
Password::broker('admins')->sendResetLink($request->only('email'))
```

Answer (score 2):

Override the broker function :-

- in your `PasswordResetLinkController.php`, add the following function;

```
    /**
     * Get the broker to be used during password reset.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\PasswordBroker
     */
    public function broker(): \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\PasswordBroker
    {
        return Password::broker('admins');
    }
```

- Now update the store function in `PasswordResetLink.php` by replacing

```
    $status = Password::sendResetLink(
            $request->only('email')
        );
```

to

```
    $status = $this->broker()->sendResetLink(
            $request->only('email')
        );
```

That should do it!

Comment: An exception is being thrown in this line  =>  return Password::broker('admins');
ErrorException
Undefined array key "expire"

Comment: Where is the 'expire' key coming from? You could be having another error not from password broker but mutually related. Could you share the whole exception error message?

Answer (score 1):

In config/auth.php

```
'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],

        'tenant' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'tenant',
        ],
///
'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Models\User::class,
        ],

        'tenant' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Models\Tenant\User::class,
        ],
    ],
///
'passwords' => [
        'users' => [
            'provider' => 'users',
            'table' => 'password_resets',
            'expire' => 60,
            'throttle' => 60,
        ],
        'tenant' => [
            'provider' => 'tenant',
            'table' => 'password_resets',
            'expire' => 60,
            'throttle' => 60,
        ],

    ],
```

In the config/fortify.php file

```
    'passwords' => ['users','tenant'],
```

extend the PasswordBrokerManager class and override the broker method like

```
public function broker($name = null)
    {
        $name = $name ?: $this->getDefaultDriver();
        if (Tenancy::getTenant()) {
            return $this->brokers[$name[1]] ?? ($this->brokers[$name[1]] = $this->resolve($name[1]));
        }
        else
            return $this->brokers[$name[0]] ?? ($this->brokers[$name[0]] = $this->resolve($name[0]));
    }
```

In my case, I check for tenant environment. You can customize your by your needless, in your case for admin or user guard